# How to load some specific elements in a folder in python

Tags: python, file, dataset, loading

I have a folder like this:

```
/foo
  1.txt
  2.txt
  2.jpg
  3.txt
  4.txt
  5.txt
  5.jpg
```

There are images that corresponds to **some** of the .txt files. What I want to do is to load all txt files in this folder including its file name into a python 2D array.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
import hjson
import os


for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("/foo"):
    for file in files:
        fileName=os.path.join(subdir, file)
        if(fileName.endswith(".txt")):
            f1 = open(fileName, "r", encoding='utf-8')
            code = f1.read()
            #Here You can find all the .txt files in /foo directory
```